# Error in creating Procedure in my SQL workbench

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE temp (IN empId INT)
        BEGIN
         DECLARE emptype VARCHAR;
            SELECT emptype = qoute(emptype) FROM dms_document WHERE id =  empid;
                SELECT emptype,

     CASE  
    WHEN emptype = 'P' THEN doctype;

    ELSE 'No Documents required';
    END CASE ;
    FROM dms_report WHERE pilot = 1
End;
```

I am trying to create procedure in my sql workbench but I am getting keyword Error. Why is this error coming please help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE temp ( empId INT)
    BEGIN
     DECLARE var_etype VARCHAR(36);

SELECT 
    emptype = QOUTE(emptype)
FROM
    dms_document
WHERE
    id = empid;
SELECT 
    emptype,
    CASE
        WHEN emptype = 'P' THEN doctype
        ELSE 'No Documents required'
    END
FROM
    dms_report
WHERE
    pilot = 1;
End//
DELIMITER ;
```

run this and Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

Notes first:

- Add `DELIMITER $$` at start and `$$ DELIMITER` at end
- `VARCHAR` needs a length, example: `VARCHAR(45)`
- `CASE` doesn't need a semicolon  at each line.
- Ending `CASE` with just `END` no need for a `CASE ;` at the end

The final code should look like this, give it a try:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE temp (IN empId INT)
        BEGIN
         DECLARE emptype VARCHAR(45);
            SELECT emptype = qoute(emptype) FROM dms_document WHERE id =  empid;
                SELECT emptype,

     CASE  
    WHEN emptype = 'P' THEN doctype

    ELSE 'No Documents required'
    END  
    FROM dms_report WHERE pilot = 1;
End $$ DELIMITER ;
```